# NodeJS/fs.readdir - Ignore certain subdirectories when scanning for a specific set of subdirectories (closed)

Tags: node.js, readdir

Say we have a working directory containing subdirectories like so:

```bash
<workDir>
|— UselessFolder
|— NotThisFolder
|— SkipThisFolder
|— UsefulFolder
|— UsefulFolder2
|— UsefulFolder3
```

Is there a way that I can ignore the `UselessFolder`, `NotThisFolder` & `SkipThisFolder` subdirectories while scanning the working directory with `fs.readdir`?

The goal of the function that requires this, is to find the very last instance of the `UsefulFolder` subdirectories and do work with them later on. The function works fine most of the time, but it breaks in some cases due to the subfolders that I want to ignore that were stated above, I know this because if I completely remove the subfolders I want my function to ignore, the function will work fine, but in my case I can't delete any of the subdirectories within the working directory, so the only option is to ignore the ones I don't care about.

The code I'm currently using in my function to read the working directory and list its subdirectories is the following:

```js
var workDir = '/home/user/workDir';

fs.readdir(workDir, { withFileTypes: true }, (error, files) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log('An error occured while reading the working directory! \n\n')
        console.log('Reason: ' + error);
        return;

    } else {
        var folderList = files
            .filter((item) => item.isDirectory())
            .map((item) => item.name);

        console.log(folderList);
    };

});
```

Comment: Do your useful and/or useless directory names have a pattern that you can filter on?

Comment: In my case the `UselessFolder`, `NotThisFolder` & `SkipThisFolder` subdirectories will always have the same name.

Comment: I don't need to worry about the instances of `UsefulFolder` because the part of the function that handles those is fine, I just need to filter out the `UselessFolder`, `NotThisFolder` & `SkipThisFolder` subdirectories in order for those specific subdirectories to not interfere with the work the function will be trying to do with the `UsefulFolder` instances, if that makes sense.

Comment: Then you should be able to add more conditions where you're calling the `filter` function. Have you tried that?

Comment: No I haven't, I didn't think it would be as simple as that, then again I am new to using `readdir` with the `fs` module, I can use `writeFile, mkdir, copy` but `readdir` I'm new to.

Comment: So something like ```var folderList = files
            .filter((item) => item.isDirectory());
            .filter((item) => item.isDirectory('UselessFolder'));                                     
            .map((item) => item.name);```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to ask `readdir` itself to give you a filtered list. You will need to filter them yourself, something like this:

```js
let unwantedDirs = ['foo', 'bar'];
var folderList = files
  .filter((item) => 
    item.isDirectory() && 
    !(unwantedDirs.includes(item.name)))
```

Comment: Yep this does exactly what I need, however the instance of `unwantedDirs.contains()` needed to be changed to `unwantedDirs.includes()` because it's said that `contains()` is deprecated and that `includes()` should be used in it's place, I did this and it worked beautifully, thank you sir.

Comment: Thanks @Morsmalleo. I have approved your edit to the answer.